# Error when deploying a smart contract that implements IUniswapV2Router02

Tags: blockchain, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to implement a token and list it in pancakeswap. I got the code from babyusdt contract. I'm using truffle tool for compiling and deploying. This is the constructor:

[image]

The problem I'm having is first when I compile the contract this is shown:

[image]

But everything is fine. When I try to migrate the contract to the bsc testnet I see the following error:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I have the interface in my project and I just call the implementation like in the picture. Should I use libraries? When I remove these lines the error disappears. Please, any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Uni-swap test-net router address is :

0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1

So you need to replace the hardcoded address with this one,
I faced the same issue, it worked
For reference, I saw the post on Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/pancakeswap/comments/m1s3ki/pancakeswap_on_bsc_testnet/